# run CLLocation through out app life cycle

Tags: ios, swift, background, cllocationmanager

Can I turn on location services and keep them running globally instead of having to turn it on in every UIViewController? I know it's not power efficient, but I would like location services to be running throughout the app instead of turning them on in each controller. One reason is I found that when I do `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation` the location is initially less accurate and then converges to a more accurate position.

Ideally: it would work like:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        /// LOCATION MANAGER
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

And then anywhere in my app I would like to call:

```
if let location = locationManager.location {
// get the location info immediately
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you can fetch the location in App Delegate and use it anywhere you want. You can create a Singleton Class for location Manager. Because in the future there would be more code in your App Delegate. So try to create a new class and just call that singleton class from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Ok, so if I create a class and initialize it in the App Delegate, anywhere else I call it won't reinitialize the class in the app?

Comment: First of all why do you want to reinitialize it, Second thing you are creating a Singleton Class which means it will take the memory only one time in the App. You can access the methods and functions of that class anywhere in the App. For you reference please read this link:- https://learnappmaking.com/singletons-swift/

Comment: To be clear, I do NOT want to reinitialize it, Reading it now.. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I forgot to tell you that singleton class won't initialize again in the App.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Singletons`, you can use location anywhere in code. Singletons are objects that should only ever be created once, then shared everywhere they need to be used. You can create a separate class for accessing location

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationSyncManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = LocationSyncManager()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    private init(){}

    func requestForLocation() {

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

   //add delegate methods
}
```

And you can access it in `AppDelegate`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     LocationSyncManager.shared.requestForLocation()

    }
}
```

You can also take reference: https://medium.com/@nimjea/singleton-class-in-swift-17eef2d01d88